# Deploy Odoo with KEYCDN

Tags: odoo, cdn, odoo-9

I want to deploy odoo with KeyCDN.I have properly create pull zone and resource is access via pullzone url.But somehow when I see the path of css or image, It is not change, it comes from server only not from cdn server.I have also add CDN url in odoo configuration.

Am I missing somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely a settings issue in Odoo. Double check the settings and paths you are using. Follow the [Odoo CDN integration](https://www.keycdn.com/support/odoo-cdn-integration/) guide. Contact KeyCDN support if you still struggle with the setup.

Comment: Problem aside from odoo.As i can access my resources from generated CDN url, but somehow website cant fetch resources from CDN.                     I have recheck odoo configuration more than once.                                                          Is there any other setting than CDN Base URL and CDN Filters?